# Loop through the range and then sheets and delete rows based on cell value

Tags: vba

I'm working on a loop that will feed of a cell in sheet "Results" and go through number of worksheets (at the moment set to 1-3) and delete the row where it finds the value from sheet "Results". At the moment it fails, can you please advise?

```
Sub Del_Rows()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, del As Range
Dim sht As Worksheet

For x = 1 To 3
    Set sht = Sheets(x)
    Set del = Sheets("Results").Range("A13")

    Set rng = Intersect(sht.Range("A1:A2000"), sht.UsedRange)
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If (cell.Value) = Sheets("Results").Range("A13") Then 
        If del Is Nothing Then
            Set del = cell
        Else
            Set del = Union(del, cell)
        End If
    End If
    Next cell

    If del Is del Then del.EntireRow.Delete

Next x

End Sub
```

Also, I understand it might be a lot trickier to do but is it possible for the code to have a look at the dynamic range in sheet("Results") one by one?

What I mean is e.g. the code takes the value of Sheets("Results").Range("A13") and does the search for the value across the sheets 1-3 deleting rows when it finds it, and then it moves to Sheets("Results").Range("A14") and does the same thing.

Since the data in [Sheets("Results").Range("A13") + last row] is dynamic it simply does the same thing until it reaches the end (e.g. Sheets("Results").Range("A20").

Thanks a lot

Comment: I've rollback-ed your question : you shouldn't use the answer's code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to work on my initial code and came up with the following solution, which works for me.

```
Public Sub Loop_DEL()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer
'----------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, rng5 As Range, rng6 As Range, rng7 As Range, rng8 As Range, c As Range
Dim rngToDel2 As Range, rngToDel3 As Range, rngToDel4 As Range, rngToDel5 As Range, rngToDel6 As Range, rngToDel7 As Range, rngToDel8 As Range
Dim lastRow As Long

With Worksheets("Results")
   lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng1 = .Range("A3:A" & lastRow)
End With

Set rng2 = Worksheets("ANY SCORE").Range("A:A")
Set rng3 = Worksheets("Page1").Range("A:A")
Set rng4 = Worksheets("Page2").Range("A:A")
Set rng5 = Worksheets("Page3").Range("A:A")
Set rng6 = Worksheets("Page4").Range("A:A")
Set rng7 = Worksheets("Page5").Range("A:A")
Set rng8 = Worksheets("Page6").Range("A:A")

For Each c In rng2
   If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng1, 0)) Then
   If rngToDel2 Is Nothing Then
   Set rngToDel2 = c
   Else
   Set rngToDel2 = Union(rngToDel2, c)
End If
End If
   Next c
   If Not rngToDel2 Is Nothing Then rngToDel2.EntireRow.Delete

For Each c In rng3
   If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng1, 0)) Then
   If rngToDel3 Is Nothing Then
   Set rngToDel3 = c
   Else
   Set rngToDel3 = Union(rngToDel3, c)
End If
End If
   Next c
   If Not rngToDel3 Is Nothing Then rngToDel3.EntireRow.Delete

For Each c In rng4
   If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng1, 0)) Then
   If rngToDel4 Is Nothing Then
   Set rngToDel4 = c
   Else
   Set rngToDel4 = Union(rngToDel4, c)
End If
End If
   Next c
   If Not rngToDel4 Is Nothing Then rngToDel4.EntireRow.Delete

For Each c In rng5
   If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng1, 0)) Then
   If rngToDel5 Is Nothing Then
   Set rngToDel5 = c
   Else
   Set rngToDel5 = Union(rngToDel5, c)
End If
End If
   Next c
   If Not rngToDel5 Is Nothing Then rngToDel5.EntireRow.Delete

For Each c In rng6
   If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng1, 0)) Then
   If rngToDel6 Is Nothing Then
   Set rngToDel6 = c
   Else
   Set rngToDel6 = Union(rngToDel6, c)
End If
End If
   Next c
   If Not rngToDel6 Is Nothing Then rngToDel6.EntireRow.Delete

For Each c In rng7
   If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng1, 0)) Then
   If rngToDel7 Is Nothing Then
   Set rngToDel7 = c
   Else
   Set rngToDel7 = Union(rngToDel7, c)
End If
End If
   Next c
   If Not rngToDel7 Is Nothing Then rngToDel7.EntireRow.Delete

For Each c In rng8
   If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng1, 0)) Then
   If rngToDel8 Is Nothing Then
   Set rngToDel8 = c
   Else
   Set rngToDel8 = Union(rngToDel8, c)
End If
End If
   Next c
   If Not rngToDel8 Is Nothing Then rngToDel8.EntireRow.Delete

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds", vbInformation

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test the code, so maybe there's some syntax error or typo.

```
Dim wb as workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
set rsws = wb.worksheets("Results")
dim lastResult as Long
lastResult = rsws.Usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCelltypeLastcell).Row 'count the last row of ResultSheet.
dim lastrowCheck as Long

for each ws in wb.worksheets 'loop through each worksheet
  lastrowCheck = ws.Usedrange.SpecialCells(xlCelltypeLastcell).Row
  if ws.name <> "Results" then
     for i = 1 to lastResult 'loop through each Result range cell
        for j = 1 to lastrowCheck  'loop throught and check value
           if rsws.cells(i,13) <> vbNullString then
                if rsws.cells(i,13) = ws.cells(j,1) then 'I suppose that it's in the first column.
            'your deleting code here
                end if
            end if
         next j
     next i
  end if
next ws
```

Below is the actual code in my excel which includes some debug print.

```
Sub testtesttest()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set rsws = wb.Worksheets("Results")
Dim lastResult As Long
lastResult = rsws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 'count the last row of ResultSheet.
Dim lastrowCheck As Long

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets 'loop through each worksheet
  lastrowCheck = ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
  Debug.Print "lastrowCheck "; lastrowCheck
  Debug.Print ws.name
  If ws.name <> "Results" Then
     For i = 1 To lastResult 'loop through each Result range cell
        For j = 1 To lastrowCheck  'loop throught and check value
           If rsws.Cells(i, 13) = ws.Cells(j, 1) Then 'I suppose that it's in the first column.
            'your deleting code here
             Debug.Print "good good good"
            End If
         Next j
     Next i
  End If
Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look when am back home. Much appreciated William.

Comment: Hi William, I have tried it and it's not working, especially in the line starting "For Each ws" - please see my amendments to your code (I have posted it in my question).

Comment: Hi, Wheeliam. Sorry that I forgot to add the .Worksheets.  for each ws in wb.worksheets. I checked the code this time and it could be running and debug.print my testing information. So it should be working this time.

Comment: I get a "mismatch" in line starting: if rsws.cells(i,13)

Comment: I just added a Null check. if rsws.cells(i,13) <> vbNullString then. Would you mind post one of your Range("A13") 's value here please? I could not reproduce the error message.

Comment: Not sure why but on both I get "Run Time Error 13 mismatch" But perhaps because while testing it, I have not added my "deleting code"?

Comment: Try debug.print the ws.name ,i,j and see where it stucks. It seems that additional process is needed for matching A13 and the A1:A2000's value on another sheet. You can get a new copy of your workbook and test with just tens of rows of data. Which will help you debug faster. I am going out now so I will not be here in the next few hours. I will answer your question when I'm back. Good luck.

Comment: I have added Rows(j).entirerow.delete replacing 'your deleting code here but it's removing all rows in sheets <>"Results". Can you advise please?

Comment: The code just helps match the cell values between 2 sheets. If you would like to remove the rows on "Result" sheet. You could add this line of code
rsws.Cells(i, 13).EntireRow.Delete  or rsws.Cells(i,13).EntireRow.ClearContents. The later one is more stable but you need additional code to clean the empty rows after "i loop". I think you should easily find the cleaning code here easily.

Comment: You could use a separate Sub to clean the empty rows later if you don't know where to put the cleaning code in the current procedure or loops.